# Enter key listener on TableItem inside CheckboxTableViewer not being triggered by enter key

Tags: java

I have a CheckboxTableViewer. This table contains some checkboxes, however they are technically "TableItem" elements. I am trying to add an enter key listener to each element because they do not natively handle the enter key. However, after adding a listener to each element, when I hit the enter key the event is not getting triggered.

Here is the private method where I set the event on each element in the CheckboxTableViewer:

```
private static void configureCheckboxListeners(CheckboxTableViewer resourcesTableViewer,
        List<Resource> resources)
{
    for (Resource resource : resources)
    {
        for (TableItem item : resourcesTableViewer.getTable().getItems())
        {
            item.addListener(SWT.Traverse, e -> {
                if (e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN)
                {
                    e.doit = false;
                    item.setChecked(!item.getChecked());
                    item.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, null);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I am aware that this is not the best way to iterate through the list, but I am not worried about that right now, I know that this hits each element in the list properly. Is there another way to hit this enter key event?

Any help at all is much appreciated!

I tried to add a listener to each TableItem element in the list of items in the CheckboxTableViewer. I expected these enter key events to get hit as I tab through each checkbox and hit enter on them. However, this did not happen. In fact, none of the enter key events are being triggered. I use this exact same selection event to set listeners for the enter key on Button controls in the same Composite however it just doesn't seem to work for the CheckboxTableViewer.

Comment: I've tried adding a listener to each element, but none of them have been acting like a listener is even there. I'm beginning to think that these buttons don't handle the enter key at all